# How to extract the city from the complete map of country in QGIS?

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, qgis

I want to ask how can I extract and filter the Karachi city from the whole map of Pakistan?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQUoE.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an attribute with this information, you can do a selection by attribute ("select feature using an expression" in QGIS).

Then you can save this selection as a new layer.

If not, you can create another layer representing your area of interest (is it the yellow circles in the image you provided?) and intersect it with your original layer.

*NB: This question should rather be on the [GIS dedicated forum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).*

Comment: I am new to QGIS, how to do this task?

Comment: 1. In which format is your data? 2.Do you have an attribute (column) that you can use you to filter your data (in Karachi city or not)? 3. What are the circles in the image you provided?

Comment: I have uploaded the OpenStreetMap data of Pakistan. I also have another dataset to integrate with it known as places dataset which has an attribute of Address but not City and the records are in 100k+. Is their a way I can cut the the map of Pakistan for Karachi city?

Comment: Maybe the easiest would be to manually select the features that correspond to the area of Karachi. See: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#selecting-features Your selected features will be displayed in yellow. Then you can create a new layer from you selection. See: https://www.gislounge.com/save-selection-new-file-using-qgis/ Don't forget to check the option "Save only selected features" before saving.